# How do you connect to VPN with IKEV2 with EAP-TLS authentication on Ubuntu 16.0.4?

Tags: vpn, tls, ipsec

I've recently received three files called:

1. vpn-host-certificate.cer
2. company-ca-certificate.cer
3. [me.p12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12)

My work environment is Ubuntu 16.0.4. It has been requested that I connect to a VPN that is using [IKEV2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange) with [EAP-TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP_Transport_Layer_Security_(EAP-TLS)) for authentication using the provided files. I have attempted to use [StrongSwan's Network Manager](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager) with little success due to my lack of experience and inability to find documentation for this particular scenario.

Edit: The server I am attempting to connect to is an AWS EC2 instance running StrongSwan.

Using these files, I can confirm that I have connected to the VPN using Windows 10 and Mac Operating Systems.

**Can anyone explain how to connect to this VPN on Ubuntu 16.0.4 or provide documentation that explains this process for someone inexperienced in Network Engineering?**

Just to clarify, [I am not looking to setup a server using this authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-configuring-vpn-authentication), since most of the documentation online demonstrates how to do this.

<kbd>Below is an error after following the StrongSwan Network Manager Documentation</kbd>

`/var/log/syslog
Apr  9 12:13:51 username NetworkManager[1090]:   [1523301231.5138] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="0e8b3631-6f8d-4bbb-b1ec-0caa5d0f65b1" name="Company" pid=12248 uid=1000 result="success"
Apr  9 12:13:51 username NetworkManager[1090]:   [1523301231.5182] vpn-connection[0x24f7440,0e8b3631-6f8d-4bbb-b1ec-0caa5d0f65b1,"LocusLabs",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 32099
Apr  9 12:13:51 username kernel: [ 6290.067183] charon-nm[32099]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fbb2b35d746 sp 00007ffdf0af79c8 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7fbb2b2d2000+1c0000]
Apr  9 12:13:56 username NetworkManager[1090]:   [1523301236.7767] vpn-connection[0x24f7440,0e8b3631-6f8d-4bbb-b1ec-0caa5d0f65b1,"Company",0]: Timed out waiting for the service to start`

Comment: But you've only described the type of authentication used. What type of VPN is actually being used here on the server? Cisco? StrongSwan? OpenVPN?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question @dobey. The server I am attempting to connect to is an AWS EC2 instance running StrongSwan. Apologies for not making this clear at first.

Comment: Did you follow the StrongSwan documentation for Network Manager to get IKEv2 working?  https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager

Comment: @ThomasWard I did follow the documentation in the wiki's NetworkManager article. Unfortunately, when I go to my Ubuntu Network panel and toggle the VPN connection from OFF to ON, I'm given a long error.

Comment: Details on that error would be useful, if possible.  Whatever the 'error' is will probably explain what broke.

Comment: @ThomasWard I've added the relevant syslog records that you had mentioned. Thanks for the advice.